# how to convert int to string with fixed length

Tags: php

I need a function that will be convert an int value to string with fixed length.

For example :

```
5 -> '000005', 5245 -> '005245' ..
```

If the number is bigger than 999999 it stays as it is:

```
2548562 -> '2548562'
```

Is there PHP function to do that, or do I need to create a custom function?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is this

```
$value = str_pad($value, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will pad your integer value with 0's as a `string`.  If there are more than 6 digits, the integer will simply stay as is.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$value = 5;

$value = str_pad($value, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

print($value . "\xA");

$value = 2548562;

$value = str_pad($value, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

print($value);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
000005
2548562
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$resultString = str_pad($value, length , '0' , STR_PAD_LEFT);
```